# Detect screen orientation in Android 2.2+

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen-orientation

I have some problem with screen orientation. Basically what I am trying to do is to determine exact screen orientation (including reverse landscape and reverse portrait). I wrote method below to do it for me and it seems to work perfectly on my Transformer however when I start same code on emulator some things are messed.

Basically what is happening is that whenever in emulator I switch to landscape (ROTATION_90) according to documentation it is supposed to be reverse landscape (and for example on Transformer with ROTATION_90 device is in reverse portrait as Android documentation describes). Unfortunately on emulator for some reason it seems to be normal landscape mode.

So my question is this code below correct ir problem lies in it. Or perhaps I am not taking into account some other parameters (like emulator has barely accelerometer enabled for instance).

```
public static int getDeviceCurrentOrientation() {

    WindowManager lWindowManager = (WindowManager) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    Configuration cfg = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    int lRotation = lWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

    int rotation1;
    int orientation;

    rotation1 = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED;
    if (cfg.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        rotation1 = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    else if (cfg.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        rotation1 = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    else
        rotation1 = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED;

    switch (lRotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        orientation = 0;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        orientation = 1;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        orientation = 2;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        orientation = 3;
        break;
    default:
        orientation = -1;
    }

    if ((orientation == 0)
            && (rotation1 == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE))
        return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

    if ((orientation == 0)
            && (rotation1 == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT))
        return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    if ((orientation == 1)
            && (rotation1 == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT))
        return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;

    if ((orientation == 1)
            && (rotation1 == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE))
        return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;

    if ((orientation == 2)
            && (rotation1 == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT))
        return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;

    if ((orientation == 2)
            && (rotation1 == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE))
        return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;

    if ((orientation == 3)
            && (rotation1 == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT))
        return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    if ((orientation == 3)
            && (rotation1 == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE))
        return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

    return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED;
}
```

Comment: I probably also should add that I know that I messed with names orientation and rotation for variables:-) Also both emulator and my tablet work with Android 4.0.3

Comment: Ok, on emulator I have just tried API 8 and API 10. With 2.2 on emulator this code worked as intended however 2.3.3 caused same problems

Comment: You haven't told us what error message you are getting. What is the logcat output?

Comment: No error. Using this method to lock orientation in case of some activities. Locking always in either portrait or landscape is not an option for me so the most natural way is to lock current orientation. I can do this without checking rotation (as I do on devices with Android 2.1 and older) but that way I can't detect reverse landscape and reverse portrait. Just when using class method above on emulator in case of API 10 and 15 screen in landscape mode is upside-down with orientation = ROTATION_90 while in case of API 8 or physical device with Android 4.0.3 everything is displayed correctly.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I just solved problem in a bit different way putting method above only for use with Froyo while I managed to adjust code in order to work with ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT and ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE

Comment: FYI, you can reduce that last batch of if statements by a lot:  if (orientation == 0 || orientation == 1) return rotation1;  else (if landscape, return reverse landscape; if portrait, return reverse portrait)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem and after hours of crunching......
I found [this nice solution >>](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/eric-miles/programmatically-locking-android-screen-orientation)

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();

Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);

int lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
        || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
    // if rotation is 0 or 180 and width is greater than height, we have
    // a tablet
    if (size.x > size.y) {
        if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
            lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        } else {
            lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
        }
    } else {
        // we have a phone
        if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
            lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        } else {
            lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
        }
    }
} else {
    // if rotation is 90 or 270 and width is greater than height, we
    // have a phone
    if (size.x > size.y) {
        if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
            lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        } else {
            lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
        }
    } else {
        // we have a tablet
        if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
            lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
        } else {
            lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        }
    }
}
```